# Selected menu highlight Razor 3 cshtml using js

Tags: javascript, css, razor

yesterday I started to translate my page or moving it from HTML5/CSS/JS/jQuery/PHP to razor 3 or rather cshtml/css/js and is now trying to get active page highlighted  in the menu.

The _SiteLayout.cshtml part:

```
<nav class="navigation">
       <ul class="active">
          <li class="unSelected"><a href="/Default" onclick="javascript:click (this);">Home</a></li>
          <li class="unSelected"><a href="/Photography">Photography</a></li>
          <li class="unSelected"><a href="/Webdevelopment">Web Development</a></li>
          <li class="unSelected"><a href="/About">About</a></li>
          <li class="unSelected"><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Css Part:

```
.navigation .unSelected a {
border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.navigation .selected a {
border-bottom: 2px solid #3acdd5;
}
```

JS part:

```
$('.navigation ul li a').click(function () {
    $('.navigation ul li a').each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).removeClass().addClass('unSelected');
    })

    $(this).removeClass('unSelected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I wan't the body link selected to be highlighted til you click the next one that should be highligted when you are there and so on, as I would have done when using html and this was set on each individual page.

As seen this won't work and I wonder if there's any way to make this work by only working with the JS and if so how.

If not, what is the best way to solve this kind of a issue?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is use the Razor engine to add the `selected` and `unselected` classes like so:

```
<li class='@(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString() == Url.Action("Default") ? "selected" : "unSelected")><!-- List item content --></li>
```

This allows you to leverage the MVC URL routing so that you don't need to do any major url parsing or hard code them anywhere. However, my answer may not be all encompassing for cases where you have a query string as part of the URL.

**Update:** I just did a test on my own project and it looks like `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` doesn't include the query string. Of course, had I looked at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath(v=vs.110).aspx), I would have noticed that it states the query string information is not included and not added this update

Comment: This sounds like a good way of doing it, I realize that I need to do some more reading about Razor. Is there any specific "using" or script that should be added to the code for this to work? If I just rewrite the same code in to my project I get a error underneath the "Url" at "Url.Action("Default")" saying that it dosen't exist in this context.

Comment: I would check the `web.config` in the Views folder and make sure that it includes, in the `<namespaces>` tag `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc />`. Usually this is included in the `web.config` when you create/switch to an MVC app, but it's possible the file is corrupt. You **will** need to unload and reload the project or reload the solution for the change to affect the intellisense

Comment: the full <page> and there with <namespaces> etc. was missing, added them and restade the full VS loaded i nthe project again but the same problem is still there :/

Comment: Just want to make sure, you updated the `web.config` in the Views folder, and not the one in the project root folder, correct? I did that the other day only to realize that it must be the one in the views folder. But outside of that I would try the `@using System.Web.Mvc;` statement in the `.cshtml` file. If that doesn't fix it I would double check you have the reference in the project. Beyond that, I can't say I know off-hand and would suggest searching SO :/

Comment: Apperantly there's not a Views folder, tried to create a new project to see if there was any in it, but non there either :/ Also tried doing "System.Web.Mvc.Url.Action" but then says that Url not exist in System.Web.Mvc, hm.

Thank you so much for your time and help by the way

Comment: I'd double check the system.web.Mvc is in your project references. But making a new MVC app should automatically include those in the project base :/ but if they aren't part of a new project then there may another issue at hand which I can't say I know what to do with at this point :/